# Blender change bevel via gui or python doesn't work

Tags: python, blender

I use Blender 2.79.
I have two window for one blender file for two screens (laptop and monitor).
One screen is for scene only and other, smaller is for tools.
When I try to change bevel via gui, I go to **DataBlocks**/**Objects**/**Cube**/**Data**/**Cube.001**

Than I go to **..**/**Edges**/**Mesh Edge** and I try to change Bevel Weight to 1.0 for 4th edge (index 3).
I am in Object mode, not Edit mode with object.
And nothing happened.
When I try to change that with python via python console, I use:

```
>>> cube = bpy.context.active_object
>>> cube.data.edges[0]
bpy.data.meshes['Cube.001'].edges[0]
>>> cube.data.edges[3].bevel_weight 
0.0
>>> cube.data.edges[3].bevel_weight = 1.0
>>> cube.data.edges[3].bevel_weight
1.0
```

But nothing happened on screen view.
There is no bevel.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15071/935) is what you are after.